# Creating Hyperlink to variable cell location in another sheet, using name from current sheet

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I'm trying to link from a sheet back to my summary sheet. I want hyperlink to a specific cell in the summary sheet which has the same name as a cell in my current sheet. The cell location in the summary sheet is prone to changing locations, so I can't do a direct hyperlink. I was thinking to use HYPERLINK + INDIRECT, but can't get it working.

This is what my formula looks like so far, though it's clearly incorrect:

=HYPERLINK(INDIRECT("Summary!'"&A5&"'"))
Where A5 is the location in my current sheet (called 'sheet 3') with a value of 'sheet 3', and I want to go to the cell in the summary page that has the value 'sheet 3'.

Comment: I think you are missing the `'` symbols

Comment: If `A5 = 'sheet 3'`, then this formula is looking for `"SUMMARY!'sheet 3'` which is probably not valid cell reference. `A5` needs to reference a cell location somehow. The equation is expecting something like `SUMMARY!B39`

Comment: That's why I was using INDIRECT as well. I have successfully used it in the summary sheet in a similar manner, but only to return a value, not to hyperlink.

Comment: I see what you're saying urdearboy, but I guess that's the question I'm asking... How do I change the formula to link to the cell reference for the cell that contains that value? Because that cell reference is not fixed, and will change as rows get deleted from the summary page.

Comment: Is the cell locked to any column or row? Or it can just be anywhere?

Comment: It's always in column A, but the row varies

Comment: Thanks for your help - I finally figured out how to do it. Here's the formula I used in the end:
=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",INDEX(Summary!A:A,MATCH($A$5,Summary!A:A,0),Summary!A:A)),"Return to Summary")